# Need to make a very large array [2^16+1][2^16+1] - size of array is too large :(

Tags: c

Greetings

I need to calculate a first-order entropy (Markov source, like on wiki here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory) of a signal that consists of 16bit words. 
This means, i must calculate how frequently each combination of a->b (symbol b appears after a) is happening in the data stream.
When i was doing it for just 4 less significant or 4 more significant bits, i used a two dimensional array, where first dimension was the first symbol and second dimension was the second symbol.

My algorithm looked like this

1. Read current symbol
2. Array[prev_symbol][curr_symbol]++
3. prev_symbol=curr_symbol
4. Move forward 1 symbol

Then, Array[a][b] would mean how many times did symbol b going after symbol a has occurred in a stream.

Now, i understand that array in C is a pointer that is incremented to get exact value, like to get element [3][4] from array[10][10] i have to increment pointer to array[0][0] by (3*10+4)(size of variable stored in array). I understand that the problem must be that 2^32  elements of type unsigned long must be taking too much.

But still, is there a way to deal with it?

Or maybe there is another way to accomplish this?

Comment: How many symbols are in the data stream?

Comment: Arrays in C *are not pointers*.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to use a 64 bit platform/OS/compiler with sufficient memory.

Answer (score 5):

An two-dimensional array of integers (4 byte) with 32'000 by 32'000 elements occupies about 16 GByte of RAM. Does your machine have that much memory?

Anyhow, out of the more than 1 billion array elements, only very few will have a count different from zero. So it's probably better to go with some sort of sparse storage.

One solution would be to use a dictionary where the tuple (a, b) is the key and the count of occurrences is the value.

Comment: I see, dictionary seems a much better solution than array in this case. It is just i never thought about that because program started as 4bit analyzer and for that, it was easier to use 16x16 array..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do multiple passes over the data. The entropy contribution from pairs beginning with symbol X is essentially independent of pairs beginning with any other symbol (aside from the total number of them, of course), so you can calculate the entropy for all such pairs and then throw away the distribution data. At the end, combine 2^16 partial entropy values to get the total. You don't necessarily have to do 2^16 passes over the data, you can be "interested" in as many initial characters in a single pass as you have space for.

Alternatively, if your data is smaller than 2^32 samples, then you know for sure that you won't see all possible pairs, so you don't actually need to allocate a count for each one. If the sample is small enough, or the entropy is low enough, then some kind of sparse array would use less memory than your full 16GB matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Did a quick test on Ubuntu 10.10 x64

```
gt@thinkpad-T61p:~/test$ uname -a
Linux thinkpad-T61p 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:44 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gt@thinkpad-T61p:~/test$ cat mtest.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

short *big_array;


int main(void)
{
    if((big_array = (short *)malloc(4UL*1024*1024*1024*sizeof (short))) == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }

    big_array[0]++;
    big_array[100]++;
    big_array[1UL*1024*1024*1024]++;
    big_array[2UL*1024*1024*1024]++;
    big_array[3UL*1024*1024*1024]++;

    printf("array[100] = %d\narray[3G] = %d\n", big_array[100], big_array[3UL*1024*1024*1024]);

    return 0;
}
gt@thinkpad-T61p:~/test$ gcc -Wall mtest.c -o mtest
gt@thinkpad-T61p:~/test$ ./mtest 
array[100] = 1
array[3G] = 1
gt@thinkpad-T61p:~/test$
```

It looks like the virtual memory system on linux is up to the job, as long as you have enough memory and/or swap.

Have fun!